# USB seems to run fine but media check fails

Tags: release-juno, system-installation

When booting the USB the media check option simply restarts the computer, I've checked the sha256 sum and used the recommended methods (etcher and unetbootin) , can someone confirm the media check has worked for them (or that it's known to not work for anyone.)

Sorry for my first post to appear negative, just trying to point out a bug to fix. I really appreciate the work that's gone into Elementary OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried it in virtualbox, it has the correct sha256 and of course I simply select the ISO rather than copying it to a USB. It still throws an error and reboots instead of doing a media check. It seems to be broken (for everyone.)